How to anchor newel post at this position?
I've taken down the wall in our entry way to do a stair rail but ran into a situation on how I would anchor 1 newel post at the top of the stairs. There are 4 2x4s sandwiched together that goes down to the bottom floor. There is a joist to the right of the 4th 2x4. Should I anchor with a zip bolt system directly down into these vertical 2x4's or is there another idea or system I should use?
https://imgur.com/a/Qgz2071
https://imgur.com/a/Je3ZGkq
https://imgur.com/a/1Iyvs9m

Do you havea any access to the floor below?  (That construction seems peculiar...I assume the plywood is just spacers to make the 2x4 stack match the 2x6 on the side?)  Also, given that the stack there isn't square, are you wanting to make your (presumably square) newel post flush with the 2x4 adjacent to the floor, or the 2x4 that's at the drywall corner?

Joining wood end to end is a hard problem and there are few good solutions, none that I am prepared to recommend.
Use your post to replace those studs. So the post needs to be 12 feet long or something like that.
It's going to be messy installing the post, but if you want best results that's it.
Second best is you bolt it to the side of the floor joist  still messy, but less messy.
Any type of surface attachment is not not going to work well unless the balustrades are  themselves braced in two directions.

If your newels are strong enough at the bottom of the stairs and at the top beyond the corner, I have in many cases like this, used to 2 newels at either side of the corner newel to hold the corner newel steady. All the corner newel needs is to be anchored well enough so if and when the lower newel gives a little, which they all do, so the angle of the handrail coming off the starting newel, will not lift the corner newel up off its curb.
